# firebase cloud messaging: Json payload for java code to multicast messages

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Need to send the multicast messages with api call via json payload
we need to use the Firebase http v1
Currently i have implemented the single push notification, but i am unable to send the multicast messages using json payload.
we know json payload key values pairs got changed.

For single push messages

json payload is

```
{
   "message":{
      "token":"APA91bGHXQBB...9QgnYOEURwm0I3lmyqzk2TXQ",
      "data":{
        "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging device group message!"
      }
   }
}
```

what is the json payload for multicast messages
i need know what is the key value for to send device token in the payload

Answer (score 0):

The ability to send messages to multiple tokens with a single call was removed in the versioned API of Firebase Cloud Messaging. You will need to make a separate call for each message.

From the Firebase documentation on [sending messages to multiple devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices):

> **Important**: The send methods described in this section were deprecated on June 21, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. For protocol, instead use the standard [HTTP v1 API send method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send), implementing your own batch send by iterating through the list of recipients and sending to each recipient's token. For Admin SDK methods, make sure to update to the next major version. See the Firebase [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#fcm-depr-features) for more information.

Key from that FAQ is this bit:

> Action required: Migrate to the standard HTTP v1 API send method, which supports HTTP/2 for multiplexing.

So if you need to send many messages this way, you can use HTTP/2 multiplexing to reduce resource usage. That's what the Firebase Admin SDKs do for example.